# Реализовать функцию, которая проверяет, содержит ли строка только символы 'a', 'b', 'c' или нет

Tags: java, регулярные-выражения

Как написать регулярное выражение для решения данной задачи?

Необходимо, чтобы это выражение захватывало множественное вхождение каждого из символов в любом сочетании и исключало наличие любых других символов.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

любой из символов (один):

```
[abc]
```

сколько угодно символов (в том числе — ни одного) в любом сочетании:

```
[abc]*
```

один и более символов в любом сочетании:

```
[abc]+
```

привязка к началу (<kbd>^</kbd>) и концу (<kbd>$</kbd>) строки (строка может быть и пустой):

```
^[abc]*$
```

если должен быть хотя бы один символ, то:

```
^[abc]+$
```

---

в разных диалектах регулярных выражений может потребоваться «эскейпить» некоторые (или даже все) из перечисленных квантификаторов (<kbd>^</kbd> <kbd>[</kbd> <kbd>]</kbd> <kbd>*</kbd> <kbd>+</kbd> <kbd>$</kbd>), добавляя перед ними символ <kbd>\</kbd>. подробности уточняйте в документации к вашему движку регулярных выражений.

Comment: к сожалению, так и не смог добиться выполнения условий задачи. можете, пожалуйста, объяснить более подробно, какое регулярное выражение нужно именно для этой задачи.

Comment: одно из двух последних. какое именно — зависит от того, присутствует ли в задаче условие «строка должна содержать хотя бы один символ» или «строка может быть пустой».

Comment: попробовал сейчас использовать эти выражения, но в обоих случаях их устраивает наличие в строке хотя бы одного символа из трех, а необходимо чтобы были все.

Comment: *необходимо, чтобы были все* — это уже совершенно другой вопрос. задайте его, пожалуйста, с помощью кнопки «задать вопрос» в правом верхнем углу страницы. заодно уточните в вопросе и требования к порядку вхождения символов.

Comment: получается, с самого начала неправильно сформулировал вопрос, потому что пытался узнать именно про вхождение все трех символов. извиняюсь :(

Comment: с данным уточнением регулярное выражение будет на порядок сложнее. кстати, возможно, в условии обговорено и **количество** символов. например: «ровно по одному символу из этих трёх». не забудьте и это уточнить.